# How do I remove first three elements in Array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, api

I have this button I press that gives me access to 3 reviews. The problem Im having is that it keeps adding on to the other 3 reviews that are stored. How would I remove the first 3 reviews before adding the next 3 reviews?

```
self.fetchReviews(id: venue.id ?? "no number", locale: "en_US") { (response, error) in
guard let validResponse = response else {return}

for review in validResponse {

//This is were I append the reviews to my Array
self.resturantReviews.append(review.text!)
tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: `self.restaurantReviews = []` on the line following the `guard` will clear your array of any values.

Comment: You also have self.restaurantReviews. removeFirst(3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Removing the first 3 reviews before adding the next 3 reviews* is actually **replacing** the items.

An easy way is `map`ping the array, `compactMap` unwraps the optional safely.

```
self.resturantReviews = validResponse.compactMap(\.text)
tableView.reloadData()
```

Side note: Calling `tableView.reloadData()` inside the loop is very bad practice.